# sprite with transperent image displaying as white box when function called on background thread

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I am detecting facial features and to display the positions am creating sprite through transparent image, if i am calling the function to add sprite on main thread sprite is displaying properly but when i am calling this function on background thread or any other thread except main, it is displaying white boxes. below i have uploaded screen shot and code snippet.

[image: screen shot of output]

```
- (id)init{

       if( (self=[super init])) {

      [self addBackImageAndControls];
  }
return self;
 }

-(void)addBackImageAndControls{

    UIImage *scalledImage =[originalImage1 scaleToSize:CGSizeMake(320, 480)];
    texture2D =[[CCTexture2D alloc] initWithImage:originalImage1];

    [self body_init];

    self.isTouchEnabled = YES;

    CCMenuItem *done = [CCMenuItemFont itemFromString:@"Done" block:^(id sender) {[self done];}];
    done.position = ccp(40, 60);
    CCMenu *starMenu = [CCMenu menuWithItems:done, nil];//
    starMenu.position =CGPointZero;
    [self addChild:starMenu z:0 tag:125];

    //[self callFunc:scalledImage];

   [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(callFunc:) toTarget:self withObject:scalledImage];

}

-(void)done{

  md.LipRect =  [self lipRect];

  [self removeAllChildrenWithCleanup:YES];

   CCMenuItem *item1 = [CCMenuItemFont itemFromString:@"One" block:^(id sender)
      {[self sizeOne];}];
   item1.position = ccp(40, 40);

  CCMenuItem *item2 = [CCMenuItemFont itemFromString:@"Two" block:^(id sender)
    {[self sizeTwo];}];
  item2.position = ccp(110, 40);

  CCMenuItem *item3 = [CCMenuItemFont itemFromString:@"Three" block:^(id sender)
  {[self sizeThree];}];
  item3.position = ccp(180, 40);

  CCMenu *starMenu = [CCMenu menuWithItems:item1,item2,item3, nil];//
  starMenu.position =CGPointZero;
  [self addChild:starMenu];

}

 -(void)callFunc:(UIImage*)image{


   [self opencvFaceDetect:image];
   [self opencvEyeDetect:image];
   [self opencvNoseDetect:image];

   [self LipsEffect];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's updating the UI, it must be done on the main thread.  Wrap the UI updates like this:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    // UI here
});
```